# Customized rendering of elements in datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, uirepeat

I have **n** elements in an arraylist, I want to display all those in a table of (n/3) X 3 format (by single iteration) with respective number of radio buttons like,

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="2"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="4"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="5"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="6"></td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="n"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just use `h:panelGrid` and `c:forEach`

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <c:forEach items="#{myBean.list}"  var="item">
        <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

It will render a `<table />`

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

Comment: should work, but why use `c:forEach` when you have `ui:repeat`?

Comment: Thank U all, I tried this but not fulfilling my requirement. Actually I have to render radios in place of these 1,2,3... n. but if I did this based on c:forEach, one radio button itself got split into 3 columns (means 1 radio in a row divided by 3 columns). Whereas I need to render 3 radio buttons in a row (means in 3 columns)

Comment: @tt_dev ui:repeat itself is a component, while c:foreach is a taghandler. In this case here, if you use ui:repeat instead of c:foreach, then there is exactly one child for the panelgrid (the ui:repeat itself). Thus it would render everything in the first column of your grid. However, you could of course use ui:repeat instead but then you have to create the grid manually.

Comment: @Krishnan the answer completely fulfils the requirements you mentioned in the original question. If you have different requirements, then clarify your quesiton in the original post. e.g. I do not understand what you mean by "a button got split into 3 columns"?

Comment: @stg as u requested, my actual requirement updated in original post. Thanks in advance

Comment: @stg I tried c:forEach like this, `<h:panelGrid columns="3">
 <c:forEach items="#{myBean.list}" var="item">
  <input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="#{item.value}"><h:outputLabel value="#{item.desc}"/></input>
 </c:forEach>
 </h:panelGrid>`

Comment: @stg, This is the html output I got for c:forEach, `<table> <tbody> <tr> <td><input id="category1" type="radio" value="1" name="category1"></td> <td><label>Description on item 1</label></td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td><input id="category1" type="radio" value="2" name="category1"></td> <td><label>Description on item 2</label></td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> ... ... ... <td><input id="category1" type="radio" value="n" name="category1"></td> <td><label>Description on item n</label></td> <td></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`

Comment: @stg After some R&D, I found the reason why the radio buttons got displayed in 3 columns. It was due to that separate tag <h:outputLabel> used for displaying item description. After modifying radio button like `<input type="radio" name="category1" id="category1" value="#{item.value}">#{item.desc}"</input>` I found, it is fulfilling my requirement ;-)... Thanks yar...